# Is there any way to backup all mysqldatabses in single file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

Usually i have cron job to dump separate databases in separate sql file and then i can restore it.

Is there any way , any command so that i run as cron job everynight and i have single file which i can upload to `S3` like  `mysql-backup.tar.gz` which will conatin all databases , users , triggers and all other info.

I should also be able to restore with one command as well.

or at least all databases in single file with one command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man mysqldump` is your friend! In short, yes, check out the `--all-databases` option as well as the `--routines` and `--triggers` options.

To restore, simply issue mysql -u  -p < the_dump.sql

Comment: thanks for that. is it possible to backup users and previleges

Comment: Easy enough to test. Do a mysqldump with the options mentioned above, then open up the dump file in a text editor and see what you find.